# Android webview issue with SINGLE_COLUMN mode

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I'm currently having a issue with the Android `WebView`.
This webview is currently initialized like this:

```
_post_WebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_webview);
_post_WebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
_post_WebView.setWebViewClient(new PostWebViewClient());
_post_WebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
_post_WebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
_post_WebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
_post_WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
_post_WebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
_post_WebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
_post_WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
_post_WebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
_post_WebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
_post_WebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

This webview is used to display a HTML string retrieved from a server. (Using the `loadData` method). Now the problem is the fact that in `SINGLE_COLUMN` mode, the images and text are resized properly in both width and height but the embedded youtube videos, while resized in width, don't get resized in height and therefore show nothing but a black box.

In `LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL` everything works fine.
How can I make sure the youtube videos get resized properly in the `SINGLE_COLUMN` algorithm too?

The Youtube video's are embedded like this:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" width="420" src="YOUTUBE_VIDEO_LINK"></iframe>
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes I did. I've added my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally went and solved it by using `loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null)` instead of `loadData(htmlString,"text/html","utf-8")` while adding a 100% `max-width` property and a auto `width` and `height` property to the iframes using CSS:

```
htmlString = "<html><head><style>iframe {max-width: 100%; width:auto; height: auto;}</style></head><body>"+htmlString+"</body></html>";
```

It's not the most clean way to do so, but it works.

This method should also work if used with the layout algorithm `NARROW_COLUMNS`.