# Android Webview layouting SINGLE_COLUMN

Tags: android, webview

I have a quite big problem with the layout of my WebView. I'm downloading content from an RSS collector site, including the article content.
This content may contain pictures or YouTube videos or whatever else. Downloading is not the problem, but rather displaying it.

The pictures will probably be too wide to fit the screen. This is not a problem - I can resolve that by setting the LayoutAlgorithm to `SINGLE_COLUMN`.

```
_webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

However, using `SINGLE_COLUMN` creates a problem for YouTube videos. They are resized in width, but not in height - resulting in the WebView displaying only a black picture instead of the video. There is no way of playing the video like this.

I can resolve this as well by setting the LayoutAlgorithm to `NORMAL` or `NARROW_COLUMNS` - however, that results in the pictures not being resized to the screen size as I'd like, and I have to scroll right/left in order to see the whole picture (which does not work very well because I have the WebView in a horizontal PageAdapter).

I can assume this may be the reason `SINGLE_COLUMN` is deprecated ([developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html)). However, `NARROW_COLUMNS` just does not do what I'm expecting it to.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139447/2281717), the problem is that LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN - is deprecated now.
The problem is that images in your html have fixed width - you have to fix it - setting max-width

Comment: as i've also written above - i know it is depreached, however it's the only way i know to get the webview to resize the images to the screen. using 'NARROW_COLUMNS', following your link - i would have to replace all "width"/"height"-attributes inside the page, which i am still trying to prevent. However, i've found a solution now - i just replaced the iframe of the youtube-video with a image+link to the video, displaying the video in the youtube-app.

Comment: no need to use NARROW_COLUMNS - use NORMAL, but add a little fix to html - max-width - that's all.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17801942/2281717

Comment: you were right about this - I didn't think about adding it as max-width=100%. I'll mark your answer as correct one - thanks