# Youtube videos embedded in Android Webview don't play in SINGLE_COLUMN layout

Tags: android, html, video, webview, youtube

I am trying to load some HTML data into Android Webview. The data is in the form of string that is loaded from a web service and the HTML can contain embedded youtube videos which I want to embed inline and make playable.

Everything works fine with `LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL`. But when I use the `SINGLE_COLUMN` layout algorithm, the Youtube videos show up as black boxes that cannot be played anymore. I need a single column format as the images inside the HTML overflow the webview width in `NORMAL` mode. Here's my code to configure the webview.

```
// Set maximum image width to fit screen
contentWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

// Make non focusable to prevent links from being selectable.
contentWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
contentWebView.setFocusable(false);

// Enable HTML5 video
contentWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
contentWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
contentWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
});
```

Is it possible to somehow make the videos playable with `SINGLE_COLUMN` layout or emulate the single column layout manually while applying the `NORMAL` layout algorithm? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN - is deprecated on
[google developers.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html)
You have to change width/height of elements in your html string if you can.

In my case i replace all height="", width="" - and it works great without any setLayoutAlgorithm() settings.
Or try this  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17801942/2281717)