# LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN is deprecated on KitKat 4.4, what is the workaround?

Tags: android, webview

I have a web page that includes images that are wider than the device screen. `NARROW_COLUMNS` doesn't resize the image to fit the screen, whereas `SINGLE_COLUMN` scales it down so the user cannot scroll horizontally (which is what I want).

`SINGLE_COLUMN` works fine till 4.3 as i have verified but on 4.4 it doesn't give the desired effect as it's depricated because they changed the [Webcore.h](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/page/Settings.h) class which `LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN` is embed to.

My question is that whether there is a workaround to achieve this since I've seen that Chrome, Firefox and Opera are still able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
String htmlString = "<html><head><style>iframe {max-width: 100%; width:auto; height: auto;}</style></head><body>"+htmlString+"</body></html>";
loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Not the cleanest why but it's working for me and credit to this [Android webview issue with SINGLE_COLUMN mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450370/android-webview-issue-with-single-column-mode/17801942#17801942)

Comment: No you need to get the html string of the web

Comment: Yes something like that! And putting the content to the iframe with css

Comment: It's not working. I'm still able to scroll horizontally and the images aren't loading at all.